# How to break down eloquent query ::with()

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

When using eloquent single table query like this

```
$query = Lists::query();
```

we can save in a temporary variable, but when we use multiple tables like this

```
Lists::with(['tags','keyproduct','productcatalog']);
```

why can't we save it in a variable like above? The reason I want to store in a temp variable like this is because I wanted conditional statement in the query like

```
if($something==true)
   $query->where('type'=>'Paid')
```

Any idea how to break down the query using ::with()?

Answer (score 0):

you can give condition in whrehas

```
$posts = List::whereHas('comments', function($q)
{
if($something==true){
$q->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
}
})->get();
```

For more details http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: umm how about other tables in the with and where is the if statement in yr query ?

Comment: It was an example. `$query` holds your subquery for you to use. You could, for example, just wrap a `$query->where()` within an if statement.

Comment: i c but after the callback where do i add others two tables name? ::whereHas('comments', function($q) {}, 'keyproducts', 'productcatalog') like that?